# windowsformhost cant load a usercontrol from another dll

Tags: wpf, windowsformshost

So I have a dll from another project which contains many useful classes and controls for me (lets call it foo.dll). I'm making an WPF app. I need to use some of them in my app. I created my usercontrol for windows forms and referenced UserControlForMe from foo.dll. It's shown, all good. Now I want to insert my usercontrol into a wpf form. It looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FlatRectangular_Profile.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
          xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:FlatRectangular_Profile.UC"
          Height="2093" Width="717">
    <Grid Name="grid">
        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <uc:WindowsFormsProfManual ></uc:WindowsFormsProfManual>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But here I get an error "cant load type UserControlForMe from foo.dll". No info on that error. Again, UserControlForMe loads in WindowsFormsProfManual. All these is going on in one class library. I referenced everything that foo.dll needed.

No idea how what to do next. I also tried to load it in code in usercontrol.loaded event, but it fails too, and shows stacktrace which leads to the constructor of the UserControlForMe.

Comment: Do you need the WindowsFormsHost? Did you try to remove it? Are we talking about a compile or runtime exception? And what exactly is UserControlForMe?

Comment: I need it because without it WPF wont load winforms usercontrol. Its during compile time. UserControlForMe is a control to draw some besier lines and I simply dont want to rewrite it in wpf control.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll have to add the assembly to your namespace import to point your application in the right direction:

```
xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:FlatRectangular_Profile.UC;Assembly=MyDLL"
```

Comment: FlatRectangular_Profile.UC  is next to the WPF control in one class library, I just added UC to the namespace not to mix them. Both controls are in one assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround since I cant get why it is not working. If I load a UserControlForMe from foo.dll *directly*  to the windowsformhost, it works. But if there is a "buffer" dll, it works in this dll, but doesnt open in futher window. Also I add a UserControlForMe programmatically to a windowsformhost.